# Update from from multiple threads of the same class

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, richtextbox

I have this class and I have a loop that launches multiple threads from the same class. This is all done from the main form.

Now I want to update the richtextbox on the main from these classes.

I have tried those begininvokes etc etc and nothing worked, no error but no output as well.

Here the code for launching the threads :

```
        Private PingObjects(100000) As Account 'Account is the class and login is the sub in it...
        PingObjects(I) = New Account
        Threads(I) = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf PingObjects(I).login)
        Threads(I).IsBackground = True
        Threads(I).Start()
```

And to update the rtb, im using MainForm.log.text = "....."
Nothing happens, no error.
I have tried using the begin invoker method as well.

Comment: Could you show the code for PingObjects.Login? (By the way, I really hope you don't plan to start 100000 threads simultaneusly)

Comment: I have already written it up there -.- anyways, again : MainForm.log.text = "....."   .Well, 100000 is just some number i put up.. those many wont be launced not even 1 % maybe.. but thats not the problem here !

Comment: You are not showing enough code.  Your `PingObjects(I)` suggest a for loop, but you did not show it.  You stated you used "begininvokes" but did not show it.  And apparently the entire content of your `login()` method is `MainForm.log.text = "....."` which does not use `Control.Invoke` (or `BeginInvoke`) and therefore will not update your UI.  So *please*, post more code.

Comment: That is the only code for now so I posted that only, and by invokes i mean those posted here on stackoverflow on other threads and got 10++ votes. I assume you know that code. The one below doesnt work as well.

Comment: .NET 4 will throw an exception if you try to modify a control from a background thread. This means that you are either gobbling the exception or not even updating the control in your login method. You HAVE to provide more code.

Comment: Its strange but that is the only code, let me tell other stuff, Account is all either Public shared or Private shared. I tried changing modifiers of richtextbox to public as well. Any mistake there ?

Comment: I see no references to a `RichTextBox` or calls to `BeginInvoke` in the code you provided. In fact, all I see is code that it is starting a new thread.

Comment: MainForm.log.text = "....." ==> I mentioned it right ?. And the invokes I didnt mention the code but I used the code below and it doesnt work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution !!

I have found the solution on another forum credits :    facebookdoom on HF

```
Delegate Sub AppenLogDelegate(ByVal update As String)
Public Sub AppendLog(ByVal update As String) Implements Interface1.AppendLog
    If log.InvokeRequired Then
        log.Invoke(New AppenLogDelegate(AddressOf AppendLog), update)
    Else
        log.AppendText(update & vbCrLf)
    End If
End Sub
```

In mainform

Make new interface class :-

Public Interface Interface1
       Sub AppendLog(ByVal update As String)
   End Interface

Put this in thread class :

Private ReadOnly _form As Interface1

Public Sub New(ByVal form As Form)
        _form = form
 End Sub

Usage :-

_form.AppendLog("aaaaaa")

Answer (score 1):

For sure,
updating controls from a thread different from the main UI thread should be done using Control.Invoke().
I have put something together for you to try

```
' at the form level
Private Delegate Sub UpdateRTB(ByVal Msg As String)

' your thread function
Private Sub Login()
    Dim Data As String = "your message for the RTB"
    rtb.Invoke(New UpdateRTB(AddressOf MainForm.UpdateRTBMessage), Data)
End Sub

' the UI updater.
Private Sub UpdateRTBMessage(ByVal msg as String)
    rtb.Text = msg
End Sub
```

I'm assuming here that your RichTextBox is named rtb

Comment: Nope, not working :/  I put this in Account.login() :  Dim Data As String = "your message for the RTB"
        MainForm.log.Invoke(New UpdateRTB(AddressOf MainForm.UpdateRTBMessage), Data)                                                                              And that function in mainform as public shared coz login is public shared as well so..

Comment: @HooCraX - care to elaborate on 'not working' is there an error? If so what is it? In order for anyone to help we need some more information

Comment: I suspect that the problem is related to the MainForm variable. From the @HooCraX comments, it seems that this is a global form instance, available in VB.NET for easying the conversion from VB6, and it's not an variable created with New. However I have not found any hints on how this is related to the problem.

Comment: @Matt Wilko, I said twice, no error but not output as well. And Steve VB6 ? no way man, It is VB.NET maybe the public shared private shared stuff doing something there ? The richtextbox updates fine from a non-threaded sub... ( from other class also ). Oh Another thing I forgot to mention, I am using a user made theme, but the normal richtextbox only, if that makes any difference...